# how to fix the error of converting numbers to letters in text files using python

Tags: python, regex

I have a code that when I enter a number in Codeheroback it was converted to a literal .
How can i fix it:

Here my code:

```
import os,re

codeheroback = str(input('Nhập Code Tướng:'))

checkskinid = '''<int name="heroId" value="" refParamName="" useRefParam="false"/>'''

with open('back.xml', 'r+' ,encoding = 'utf-8') as fileback:

    regexskinid = re.sub('name="heroId" value="(.*?)" refParamName' , 'name="heroId" value="\\1{}" refParamName'.format(str((codeheroback))) , checkskinid)

    fileback.write(regexskinid)
```

here is the returned result:

- `<int name="heroId" value="h3" refParamName="" useRefParam="false"/>`

What I want it to return:

- `<int name="heroId" value="503" refParamName="" useRefParam="false"/>`

Comment: Your "Returned result" and "What you want" are both empty.. Could you also please reduce the amount of code in your example? It's easiest for the community to find your bug when you give a *minimally reproducible* example

Comment: The FAQ about a [mcve] is worth a read. As an added benefit, the work in making such an example often fixes the bug and cleans up the code.

Comment: Also, when your code ever has `a=str(input())`, you should instead just write the input you are testing with. What input did you use to produce the returned result? What inputs should people use when trying to debug? What does this variable represent?

Comment: Looks like my question is too long so it's shortened. I fixed it

Comment: You repeatedly and pointlessly wrap stuff in `str()` for no reason; `input` already returns a `str` (so wrapping in `str` is pointless), and `str((codeheroback))` could reduce to just `codeheroback`, since `codeheroback` is already a `str` (and the extra parentheses are completely pointless). You also failed to show what you entered for the `input`, the misbehavior applies to code that depends on what you typed.

Comment: I did that in the beginning but it didn't work so I just added superfluous things

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you formatted in a number after a `\1` in the literal replacement string. `re`'s substitution syntax unfortunately can't tell the difference between a `\1` followed by a number and `\123`. Per [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax), emphasis added:

> `\number`
>
> Matches the contents of the group of the same number. Groups are numbered starting from 1. For example, `(.+) \1` matches `'the the'` or `'55 55'`, but not `'thethe'` (note the space after the group). This special sequence can only be used to match one of the first 99 groups. If the first digit of *number* is 0, **or *number* is 3 octal digits long, it will not be interpreted as a group match, but as the character with octal value *number***. Inside the '[' and ']' of a character class, all numeric escapes are treated as characters.

After formatting and string literal escapes are resolved, the substitution pattern string contains a literal `\1503`, and `\150` is the octal escape corresponding to an ASCII `h`, leaving `h3`. You can remove the ambiguity by using a version of the group backreference that is more clearly delimited thanks to additional syntactic delimiters, replacing `\\1` with  `\\g<1>` so incidental trailing digits aren't inadvertently treated as part of the escape.